# How to design a FullScreen Layout with Image, Text and GMap Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design a screen that should occupy the full Screen of Device(without ActionBar).
This screen should have ImageView at the Top, TextView In the middle , & Gmap fragment at the Bottom. SO basically it is similar to Yahoo Weather App Screen Minus the Background Image.

Can you guys suggest me how to approach to achieve this design. Which layout should i use? Any code snippet would really help.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think following Layout will help you.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgBtnSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtcenter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="center text" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtcenter"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```